# Shower engages immediately instead of using the tub spout

Tags: bathroom, shower, bathtub, spout

When I turn on my shower the water immediately goes to the shower head and not the tub spout. What's the issue? I put on a new tub spout a while back because the diverter was corroded. It seemed to work for a while and now it doesn't go to the tub. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you replace the diverter or just the spout?

Comment: Is the diverter in the spout or in the wall?

Comment: Is the new diverter corroded?

Comment: Replacing the diverter is definitely a good start as others have suggested. If that seems to not fix it, then you could have a pressure issue (pressure being too high at that point in the water path)

Comment: If your water is really hard, you might have to replace the spout every few years because mineral buildup will keep the diverter valve from working correctly.  You may be able to extend the life of the spout by soaking it in vinegar every year or two.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I replaced both the diverter and the spout, the new diverter is in the spout and isn't corroded. I also, replaced the spout and diverter about 2 months ago. It's possible the water pressure is too high, but would that change from just replacing spout and diverter?